# how to insert value for bit column of postgresql with jdbc

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, bit

If the preparedStatement sql is fixed, how can I do the insert?

## table schema

```sql
create table if not exists ttqs_a (b bit(1));
```

## code

```java
try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into ttqs_a values(?)")){
  ps.setObject(1,1, Types.BIT);
  ps.execute();
}
```

## exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "b" is of type bit but expression is of type boolean
```

Comment: If you want to store a boolean then why don't you use a `boolean`?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can tell the JDBC driver to use the data type `bit` on the database side, you you will have to add a type cast:

```sql
INSERT INTO ttqs_a VALUES (CAST(? AS bit))
```

Then use any of the types that can be cast to `bit`, such as `text`

```java
stmt.setString(1, "0");
```

or `integer`

```java
stmt.setInt(1, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks， it work.  The behavior of  setObject(..,..,Types.Bit) is by design or  bug?

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL you can use PreparedStatement#setByte to insert into BIT(M) fields, but I'm not sure whether this is also true for PostgreSQL.

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ttqs_a VALUES (?);")) {
    ps.setByte(1, (byte) 1);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

But if it's just BIT(1), why not use BOOLEAN?